# APP_INSTALLS, application_id needs to be valid. (#1815437) "

Tags: facebook, ads

"Missing or invalid field in promoted objects: For optimisation goal APP_INSTALLS, application_id needs to be valid. Please set it in promoted objects. (#1815437) "

In Facebook Ads IOS install working but for Android give this error.I tryed everything I found on internet and it's not working.

I tryed all solutions from internet without success.